# update my for loop when results when state changes in a vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I have a list of todos that I'd like to watch and auto update when a change is made in a firebase backend

Got a bit stuck on what i hope is the last step (I am using nuxtjs for a SPA)

I have a getter in my vuex store as follows

```
getMyState: state => {
      return state.todos
    }
```

I am returning this getter to my component as follows

```
computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['getMyState'])
  },
```

How do i now get my list to recognise when something has changed and update my array of results?

Thanks

Comment: The changes are made in database by another instance and you want the current instance to be updated or is the change made in current instance of spa?

Comment: My scenario is changes made from another instance and would like this instance updated. Like a live time chat app type idea.. I have already sorted the update in the same instance so when I make a post is my own added post straight away already

Answer (score 0):

Use watch property

```
 watch: {

    getMyState: function (new, old) {

    }
  },
```